# Julia: Piping operator |> with more than one argument

Tags: julia

I am attempting to pass multiple arguments to the built in piping operator in Julia `|>`.

I would like something that works like this:

```
join([randstring() for i in 1:100], " ")
```

However, using the piping operator, I get an error instead:

```
[randstring() for i in 1:100] |> join(" ")
```

I am pretty sure this is a feature of multiple dispatch with join having its own method with `delim` in the `join(strings, delim, [last])` method being defined as `delim=""` when omitted.

Am I understanding this correctly? Is there a work around?

For what is is worth the majority of my uses of piping end up taking more than one argument. For example:

```
[randstring() for i in 1:100] |> join(" ") |> replace("|", " ")
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Metaprogramming to the rescue!

We'll use a simple macro to allow piping to multi-input functions.

```
    using Pipe, Random
    @pipe [randstring() for i in 1:100] |> join(_, " ")
```

So after calling the Pipe package all we're doing is

1. using the @pipe macro
2. designating *where* where to pipe to with the underscore ("_")
   [if the function only takes one input we don't need to bother with the underscore:
   e.g.

   ```
    @pipe 2 |> +(3,_) |> *(_,4) |> println
   ```

will print "20"]

See [here](https://syl1.gitbook.io/julia-language-a-concise-tutorial/useful-packages/pipe) or [here](https://juliapackages.com/p/pipe) for more formal documentation of the Pipe package (not that there's much to document :).

Answer (score 21):

The piping operator doesn't do anything magical. It simply takes values on the left and applies them to functions on the right.  As you've found, `join(" ")` does not return a function. In general, partial applications of functions in Julia don't return functions — it'll either mean something different (via multiple dispatch) or it'll be an error.

There are a few options that allow you to support this:

- Explicitly create anonymous functions:

  ```
  [randstring() for i in 1:100] |> x->join(x, " ") |> x->replace(x, "|", " ")
  ```
- Use macros to enable the kind of special magic you're looking for. There are some packages that support this kind of thing.

Comment: WRT macros: I maintain a list at: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/5571#issuecomment-205754539